# Using Intel UPnP NAT library in C - windows

Tags: c, windows, upnp

I've downloaded Intel UPnP NAT library for C as a way to control UPnP in windows.

I cannot find ANY helpful documentations or pieces of code over the web that may help me to use the Intel UPnP NAT library properly, or even using it at all.

Any helpful URLs or pieces of code or if there's another UPnP API for windows with proper documentation?

Comment: This is not really a good question for SO, but... I don't think Intel has a UPNP NAT library. Intel did originally develop the reference UPnP implementation libupnp (which pupnp is based on) but that is plain UPnP, _not_ an implementation of a InternetGatewayDevice. If you do have a question about a specific IGD library, include a link to the project.

Comment: @jku My bad, I actually meant libUPNP :P